# Explicit Intent error

Tags: android

I want to new activity when i click an image.
I already write `activity android:name=.openPdf` in manifestfile.

but it shows me an error:-

```
"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {Parsing.this/openPdf.class}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
"
```

Code ::

```
iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent pdf=new Intent(Parsing.this,openPdf.class);
                startActivity(pdf);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure like your activity which you are launching is in the same package, then and then you can write like `android:name=.openPdf` else need to use the full class name with package.

Comment: Like  <activity android:name="com.android.sample.SampleActivity"

Comment: Please edit your answer to add new information instead of commenting on it.

Comment: nope....same error happen.i already create secondactivity in same package now i used full class name but no effect.

Comment: Please check if you have made any spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

Actually you havnt register activity in your manifest file so to overcome that
add activity tag and its Name in your Manifest file,
like...

```
<activity android:name=".openPdf" />  // "." works as a package name
```

Comment: nope....same error happen.i already create secondactivity in same package and change the manifest file. now i used full class name but no effect.

Comment: clean your project, by going project tab and also post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Parsing.this use getApplicationContext(); This may work. And instead of adding android:name=".openPdf" manually. Browse it in manifest application tag.

Cheers!!!